# Get clades by 'comment' items stored in a list with Biopython Phylo

Tags: python, loops, phylogeny

I have a phylogenetic tree in newick format and I would like to get all clades featuring 'comment' items stored in list `l = ['X','U','B','A','V','Z']`.

I can use

```
from Bio import Phylo
tree.find_elements(comment='X').next()
```

to get all clades with comment field matching 'X', but how can I iterate the same function over the comment list? 
I tried

```
tree.find_elements({"comment":'X', "comment": "U", "comment": "B"}).next()
```

but I get only the last one

```
Clade(branch_length=0.155989733231, comment='B')
```

I solved

```
nodes=[]
for i in l: 
    nodes.append(tree.find_elements(comment=i).next())
```

Comment: Did you try using a for loop ?

Comment: @M41k Dev3lops I also tried    `for i in l:
        clade = tree.find_elements(comment=i).next()`, getting always the last items

Comment: what did that return ?